# htaccess - Transform get parameter value in a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In my web application, I currently have URLs like this:

```
https://example.com/mypage?company=companyname&otherparameter=othervalue&...
```

I would like to transform the above URL this way:

```
https://companyname.example.com/mypage?otherparameter=othervalue&...
```

so basically *transforming* the value of the GET parameter "company" into a subdomain while **preserving** the other GET parameters in the URL (and preserving, obviously, also the path of the file on the server).

I also need to *exclude* the "/api" directory from this rule (so all files under the "/api" subdirectory should be served *as usual*).

I know I need to use .htaccess but I can't find a way to get it to work. If someone's got a hint, that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will capture the "subdomain name" from any incoming request and add it as query parameter to the internally rewritten target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^.]+)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/?
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?company=%1 [QSA,L]
```

This will take care of handling *incoming* requests. This does *not* somehow magically change references you hand out, so links embedded in HTML markup or javascript for example.

You need to make sure that your http server actually responds to requests to those "subdomain" based host names. A default virtual host is usually used for such thing. You also need to take care that the DNS resolution of such names works and points towards your http server. And finally you have to provide a valid SSL certificate for all those host names. A wildcard certificate is an option here, but unlike normal certificates that does not come free of charge.

It is a good idea to implement such general rules in the actual host configuration of your http server. You *can* use a distributed configuration file for this (".htaccess"), but that comes with a few disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks! And what about _transforming_ the company param to a subdirectory? So something like this: `https://example.com/companyname/filename?parameters=...` Would this be easier?

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand what you actually ask. What do you actually mean by "transforming" here? What is wrong with the solution I posted? What in that solution to you consider _not_ easy?